# How classpath is working in this example?

Tags: java

I am confused alot in java class-paths. Here is a example question and i am failed to understand the correct option. Please look at images below.

[image: Question]

[image: Options]

It states option A is correct where i thought Option C is correct. Can someone explain, why C is not the correct option and A is correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH
>   variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search
>   path, you must include "." in the new settings.

So... the C option is not correct because, it overrides the class path, and don't include the current dir, so GetJar will not be found, causing error:

```
D:\test>java -classpath MyJar.jar GetJar
Error: Could not find or load main class GetJar
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me with this concept. I am finding great difficulty in understanding classpath concepts.